# When should I use weakValues() of the MapMaker class?

Tags: java, guava

When a entry in a map has weak *key* reference, the entry will be removed at the next garbage collection, right?

I can understand that the `MapMaker` class provides the `weakKeys` method. But I am confused with the `weakValue()`. when should I use `weakValue` or `softValue` in `MapMaker`?

Answer (score 5):

You'd use `weakValues()` when you want entries whose values are weakly reachable to be garbage collected. For an example of when this might be useful... say you have a class that allows users to add objects to it and stores them as values in a `Map` for whatever reason. This class is typically used as a singleton, so it'll stick around the whole time your application is running. However, the objects the user adds to it aren't necessarily so long-lived. The application will be done with them long before it finishes. You don't want the user to have to manually remove these objects from your class when it is finished with them, but you don't want a memory leak by keeping references to them in your class forever (in other words garbage collection should just work like normal, ignoring your class). The solution is to give the map `weakValues()` and everything will work as you want.

`softValues()` is good for caching... if you have a `Map<Integer, Foo>` and you want entries to to be removable in response to memory demand, you'd want to use it. You wouldn't want to use `weakKeys()` or `softKeys()` because they both use `==` identity, which would cause problems for you (wouldn't be able to get a value with key `300` out because the key you pass in probably wouldn't `==` the key in the map).

Comment: @CollinD  Thanks for your reply. if I use softValues() instead of softKeys(), then the entry can not be removed automatically right? and when the value is reclaimed ,then I would get null even the key still exists

Comment: I would imagine that the key would go away if the corresponding value is weak/soft & GC'ed...  but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @mlaw  I'm quite sure it does, but the documentation doesn't make it clear. IMHO.

Comment: @jlchen: Soft/weak keys/values ALL exist for the sole purpose of allowing entries to be removed automatically. So yes, the entry can be reclaimed automatically.